# Can regularly added content improve SEO and achieve better ranking?

Tags: seo, content

Let's say I add a blog to a mostly static website, or simply publish new content every week.
Does that help the site rank better in search engines in any way?

Answer (score 4):

Having fresh, accurate, timely information on your site matters more than most other factors in many niches:

- News
- Weather
- Finance

If you try to make a site focused on any of these *without* regular updates, users will be unhappy with your site, and Google will be able to see users leave your site and prefer your competitors.  If you are in these niches and are trying to compete for rankings in Google News, then fresh content is king.

On the other hand, much of the content on the internet is "evergreen".  It will continue to be relevant for years.   For most sites, having fresh content is much less important than:

- The total amount of content on the site
- How useful users find the content

With evergreen content, if you have to choose between constantly creating lots of fresh content and improving existing content while adding new content more slowly, choose the slow, quality approach.

With fresh content, there is often a "honeymoon period" in the Google SERPs where Google ranks the fresh content highly to test it out.  Rankings often drop after a week or two.  Many webmasters take this as a call to keep creating fresh content.  Conversely, I have seen high initial rankings remain and even improve when the content is high quality, users react well to it, and the webmaster incorporates feedback from visitors to improve it.  It appears to me that initial rankings fall only when the content is less helpful to users than Google's algorithms initially predicted that it would be.

Comment: I like this answer, I realised what other subjects I need to look into, thank you! I quickly need to get 15 reps so that I can up-vote stuff here too ^^.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes,

You can simply Search on Google it will get proper result.

Here I just give some tips, for Good SEO ranking.

1. Periodically add valuable content [valuable means not a duplicate content from web pages and the content should point a subject that you trying to say]
2. User Friendly urls
3. Back links [The link of your website in many other good ranking site]
4. better keywords and focus on one or two keyword for a topic
5. Create sitemap and submit in Google,Bing etc.
6. Setup proper robot.txt for your site.

If you set up all the points from above you can check Google analytic for your sites improvements

Hope its give some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what everybody recommends!

Add original content and the visitors number will increase significantly.

As a matter of fact, you should be focused on that, and the backlinks will come naturally and you'll be rearded by Google!

The users will love you if you think about them first, forget about Google!

Comment: How we can forget Google while SEO stuffs ? the Google recommended things not only  improve your sites on Google its will improve every search engines